# How can I animate this button to make it wider?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

It's a simple enough question but everything I try doesn't work. I'm still pretty new to jQuery and I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. The way it's working now would be perfect if I could just get the button to slowly grow wider, and I'm not sure how to implement the animation with what I have now, or if that's even what I should do. I will have my code and a CodePen linked below.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('wider');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.wider {
  width: 40%;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}
header h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 309px;
  font-size: 400%;
}
header h1 span {
  border-bottom: 7px solid #0dc3ff;
}
#button {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
#about {
  color: white;
  font-size: 95%;
  background-color: #0dc3ff;
  border: none;
  padding: 17px 55px;
}
#about:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="caption">
            <h1><span>Independent</span> is who I am.</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="button">
            <button id="about">About Me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

http://codepen.io/Clarkpen/pen/yymGXr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the animate function on the width

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button').click(function()  {
            $(this).animate({'width':"30%"},3000);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using CSS if you want:

```
button {
  width: 10%;
}

button.wider {
  width: 30%;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in; /* For Chrome 4 - 25, Safari 3.1 - 6, Opera 11.5, iOS 3.2 - 6.1, and Android 2.1 - 4.3 */
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in; /* For Firefox 4 - 15 */
  transition: width 1s ease-in;
}
```

Will do it over the course of 1 second, with the transition occurring slower in the beginning, due to the `ease-in` property.

Comment: Do note that Firefox (and Chrome, though there are other WebKit browsers out there) has used the unprefixed `transition` for nearly three years now. Also note that there is no such thing as `ms-transition`; IE only started supporting `transition` at all in IE10, where it was supported unprefixed from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the button using CSS3 transition property.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/tsmfwaa6/),

And also using click event you can try.

> On hover

```
#about {    
    width : 50%;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;
}

#about:hover {
    width : 100%;
}
```

> On Click Event

```
$('#about').on('click', function() {
    var widthAnimate = $('#about').css({
        "width":"100%"
    })
    $(this).width(widthAnimate)
})
```